# Problem with letter pyramid, for loop not ending where i want it to c++

Tags: c++

the program will make the pyramid, and then continue one line after where it starts to repeat middle of the pyramid character, and then it will crash after. Where am I going wrong in my code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
string word;
string pyramid;
string pyramid2;

int main() {
    cout << "Enter word for the letter pyramid" << endl;
    getline(cin, word);
string whites(word.length(), ' ');
  
    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++){
        if(word.at(i) != string::npos){
            
            pyramid.push_back(word.at(i));
            
            if (i != 0){
              pyramid2 = word.at(i-1) + pyramid2;
            }
              cout << whites << pyramid << pyramid2 << endl;
          whites.pop_back();
          }
      }
    for (int x = word.size()-1; x > 0; x--){
      pyramid.push_back(word.at(x-1));
      pyramid2 = word.at(x-1) + pyramid2;
      cout  << whites << pyramid << pyramid2 << endl;
      whites.pop_back();
            }


    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Try printing out `white.size()` after the first for loop. That should get you a good idea of why there is a seg fault.

Comment: white.size() becomes 0 after the first for loop but in the second for loop you are still trying to remove elements from it, which gives the error.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys :) figured it out, the second for loop was essentially doubling the size of the pyramid, and the white spaces were running out after the first for loop!